# Dynatree node.reloadChildren() dose not always refresh tree in FireFox or IE

Tags: jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I'm using Dynatree version  $Version: 1.2.2$. I use the node.reloadChildren(); call after a call to a $.ajax function that has populated the database that represents the tree.
The problem is right after the call to node.reloadChildren(); the new leafs added to the node added do not show up in the tree. No errors/exceptions are thrown. I can tell that the .ajax function worked
because when I refresh the whole page then the nodes show up. This is not a issue In Chrome. I'm using the latest version of FireFox (21.0) and IE 10. This is a intermittent issue and sometimes it just works.

Thanks

...
...

ajxAddNewCatalogProduct(products, node);
  node.reloadChildren();

...
...
...

```
function ajxAddNewCatalogProduct(products, node) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionCode")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'products': '" + products + "', 'portalId': '" + portalId + "', 'nodeId': '" + node.data.key + "', 'nodeType': '" + node.data.Type + "'}"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajxAddNewCatalogProduct(products, node);` starts an asynchronous request and may return before it is processed.

Try to call `node.reloadChildren();` in the `success` callback of your ajax call.

Comment: Thanks that worked nicely. In fact I used the promise interface .done  callback which accomplishes the same thing.